# using null in Oracle (with regexp)-very slow

Tags: oracle, null

trying to figure out what I can do to expedite a query as when I attempt to return value based on NOT being null- it takes forever to return the observations and I need to kill the job. The regexp statement in itself seems ok.

I have masked some table names and changed var names due to IP issues. Also, I do not have a test set as it works fine in the dummy set but in the real production environment-this is where it stalls so I am looking for general concepts to address this issue.

Any input/advice appreciated. Thank you.

```
select prev_pod.mrn_id, prev_pod.pat_enc_id, prev_pod.contact_date, note_text,
coalesce(REGEXP_substr(NOTE_TEXT, '(new)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(wound)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(evaluation)',1,1,'i'), 
REGEXP_substr(NOTE_TEXT, '(foot)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(wound)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(clinic)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(new)',1,1,'i')) as STR

    
from HNO_xxx inner join PREV_POD on HNO_xxx.pat_enc_id=prev_pod.pat_enc_id
                                inner join  HNO_NOTE_TEXT  ON     HNO_xxx.note_id = HNO_NOTE_xxx.note_id and HNO_NOTE_xxx.LINE=1)

select * from ntes where STR IS NOT NULL); --THIS IS THE PROBLEM
```

Comment: regex are slow by nature, so you should start by reducing the number of rows to process by selecting the ones that could potentially match the regexp in a subquery: the ones containing (new and wound and evaluation) or (foot and wound and clinic and new).

Comment: I have it so it less than 100 rows total because of that reason- w/o selecting for when it is not null-it returns results in 2 minutes. If I attempt to select when not null-I have to kill the query after 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As written, Oracle has to read 100% of the `HNO_NOTE_TEXT` and run all its rows through your complex REGEXP logic in order to satisfy your predicate `WHERE str IS NOT NULL`. To speed this up, I suggest first of all using parallelism:

```
   select /*+ parallel(8) */ * from ntes where str is not null
```

The second thing is to check the execution plan and see if the plan has changed the join order. If you apply a predicate to `STR` (which comes from `HNO_NOTE_TEXT`) it will likely start with `HNO_NOTE_TEXT` and join to `HNO_xxx` and then `PREV_POD` in that order, whereas without the predicate it likely uses a different join order. If there are indexes on those join columns in one direction but not in the other, it can explain the difference in run time.

There's no significantly limiting predicates so you don't want indexes to be used here. Check the plan and if you see indexes in use, you may need to use the `/*+ USE_HASH(table_alias) */`  hint to force it to do full table scans + hash joins. It may decide to do that simply due to the parallel hint suggested above, but if not, edit your view:

```
select /*+ USE_HASH(hno_xxx prev_pod hno_note_text) PARALLEL(8) */ prev_pod.mrn_id, prev_pod.pat_enc_id, prev_pod.contact_date, note_text,
coalesce(REGEXP_substr(NOTE_TEXT, '(new)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(wound)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(evaluation)',1,1,'i'), 
REGEXP_substr(NOTE_TEXT, '(foot)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(wound)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(clinic)+{1,10}([^.|,|?|$])(new)',1,1,'i')) as STR

    
from HNO_xxx inner join PREV_POD on HNO_xxx.pat_enc_id=prev_pod.pat_enc_id
                                inner join  HNO_NOTE_TEXT  ON     HNO_xxx.note_id = HNO_NOTE_xxx.note_id and HNO_NOTE_xxx.LINE=1)
```

And then query it:

```
select * from ntes where STR IS NOT NULL
```

Just be aware that if others use that view and apply narrow predicates on it, those hints will hurt them. If that's the case you may be best off not using a view at all and writing your SQL directly against the tables so your hints are private.